# Panda3d Movement of camera with arrows

Tags: python, task, panda3d

I am trying to move my camera using panda3d with arrows but I get an error:
function:

```
W = KeyboardButton.ascii_key('w')
S = KeyboardButton.ascii_key('s')
def moveTask(self, task):
        is_down = base.mouseWatcherNode.is_button_down
        dt = globalClock.getDt()
        if is_down(W):
            self.camera.setX(self.camera, -20 * dt)
        if is_down(S):
            self.camera.setX(self.camera, +20 * dt)
        return task.cont
```

and where i add task:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "panda.py", line 67, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "/usr/share/panda3d/direct/showbase/ShowBase.py", line 3025, in run
    self.taskMgr.run()
  File "/usr/share/panda3d/direct/task/Task.py", line 517, in run
    self.step()
  File "/usr/share/panda3d/direct/task/Task.py", line 471, in step
    self.mgr.poll()
TypeError: moveTask() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function isn't bound to a class, so there'll be no `self`.